# Do callback functions change scope if kept separately in the same file in Angular.js 1.6.5 with angular-ui-router 0.4.1.3?

Tags: angularjs, callback, angular-ui-router, runtime, factory

I have a **factory** initialized in the index.js of my application like,

```
app.factory('userToken', function(){
  return {
    foo : function() {
        var authToken = "poop"
        return authToken 
    }
  }
})

app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'userToken', main])

function main ($rootScope, $state, userToken) {
   console.log(userToken.foo()) 
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', isAuth)
}

function isAuth (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) { 
   console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%", userToken.foo()) /* UserToken not defined */
}
```

Although I receive an error as

> The userToken is not defined.

Totally understandable. So I define the UserToken in the **isAuth function parameter** like,

```
function isAuth (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, userToken) { 
 console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%", userToken.foo())
}
```

But after doing this I get an error saying

> cannot get foo() of undefined.

So after that mess, I added the callback parameter straight next to **$rootscope.&on** event,

```
function main ($rootScope, $state, userToken) {
  console.log(userToken.foo()) 
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, 
  toState,toParams,fromState, fromParams /* Removed userToken */) {
      console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%", userToken.foo())
  })
}
```

And guess what got printed in the console

> poop.
>
> %%%%%%% poop

My question is why did it print only when I added it to the callback directly? Why not earlier when I called the function by its name **isAuth** while it was kept separate?

The userToken was out of scope which is why it gave an error earlier of it being not defined but now it ran without a hitch, why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory `userToken` is created by angular and injected into the `main` function. In this function you may then access the `userToken` factory wherever you like.

In your first example `isAuth` is defined outside of the `main` function so no longer has access to the `userToken` factory.

In your working example the function is still in the same scope as the `main` function and as such has access to the variable of the `main` function.

```
//This means on run, call the main function and inject $rootScope,
// $state and userToken
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'userToken', main])

//So teh main function is called and the above items are injected
function main ($rootScope, $state, userToken) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, 
  toState,toParams,fromState, fromParams) {
      console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%", userToken.foo()) //This references the userToken that was injected into run.
  })
}
```

Comment: So that means the userToken would be injected in the run and will only be accessible to the isAuth callback if I keep it inside the main function and not if I reference it from the main function?

Comment: Yes thats correct, you could also access it if you inject it into a controller, directive, another factory